# Using wildcards in npm scripts on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to lint all my javascript files using jshint with an npm script command.

I am running on windows and no matter what wildcard I specify I can't seem to lint more than one file.

Referencing a specific file works:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "jshint app/main.js"
}
```

But all of the following results in errors:

```
"scripts": {
    // results in Can't open app/**/*.js'
    "lint1": "jshint app/**/*.js",

    // results in Can't open app/*.js'
    "lint2": "jshint app/*.js",

    // results in Can't open app/**.js'
    "lint3": "jshint app/**.js",
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is still true as the question is from 2011 and for `jslint` but: [superuser: Wildcard for all subdirectories or all descendent directories in windows commandline](http://superuser.com/q/358863/204820)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although you can't use the wildcards when running jshint as a script task in npm on windows, you can work around it.  By default, if jshint is passed a directory, it will search that directory recursively.  So in your case you could simply do:

```
"script": {
  "lint": "jshint app"
}
```

or even

```
"script": {
  "lint": "jshint ."
}
```

This will result in all files - including those in node_modules being linted - which is probably not what you want.  The easiest way to get round that is to have a file called `.jshintignore` in the root of your project containing the folders and scripts you don't want linted:

```
node_modules/
build/
dir/another_unlinted_script.js
```

This is then a cross-platform solution for jshint as a script task in npm.